# Design drag gesture menu like YouTube to show and hide side menu which contains details of this video Chanel

Tags: ios, swiftui, youtube

I want to show profile menu like YouTube is showing. its a dragable menu. I want to implement this in SwiftUI:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

SwiftUI example to implement this type of work. I already implemented with but this is not working properly. thanks in advance.

please see attached image I want to same implementation like YouTube short videos.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gezqb.jpg

Comment: Can you add some more information about your issue? like some code snippets or things that you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "it's not working properly" is not very helpful. Please see [ask] and [edit] your question with a [example].